# Firestore / Kotlin FieldValue arrayRemove() + Firestore pricing

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore / Kotlin FieldValue arrayRemove() removes a known element on the array/list. My concern is to remove an element at a given position on the array, without konwing the element itself. Is it possible?

For instance, if my list is {"Mowgli", "Baloo", "Bagheera", "Kaa", "Shere Kahn"}, I want to remove the fisrt element "Mowgli" without knowing the name "Mowgli. Kind of:

```
FieldValue.arrayRemove([0])
```

Moreover, regarding pricing policy from google, is an 'arrayRemove' considered as a query, so that it is the same price than setting a full class of 10,000 elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My concern is to remove an element at a given position on the array, without konwing the element itself. Is it possible?

No, it's not possible.  If you want to modify an array using an index of items in that array, you have to read the document, modify the array in memory, then update the array field back to the document in its entirety.